# Editing Tableview in IB and losing connections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

I made a tableview in Interface Builder, and inserted two views for headers and footers. Eventually I realized that I needed to my footer to stay in a fixed location, so I attempted to do that by moving the prototype cell into the footer subview. When I look in the connection inspector, it looks like my connections are still there, and I made sure I still had my cell identifier. However, this code from my view controller is now throwing an exception.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the cell out of the table view in IB it wont be registered as a reusable cell.

I advise moving the contents of the cell into the footer subview and creating new outlets. Seems wacky to use a cell this way.